# Why do I have to close <br> tag in XSL?

Tags: java, html, xslt, tags

I do XSLT from time to time. So I may not understand something about it.

Not sure whether an example is necessary but here it is:
The XML is very simple:

```
<a></a>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </head>
      <body><br></body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java code:

```
public static String transform(String xml, String xsl) throws TransformerException {

    StreamSource xslT = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl));

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslT);

    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return out.toString();

}
```

I thought that if I use `html` as output type in the stylesheet then it should recognize `<br>` as a valid html tag.

And in general... Why does it care for html validity at all? I've also noticed that if I declare a variable. E.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="someTable">
<table class="common" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
</xsl:variable>
```

the same error will be reported.

My goal is not a creation of an invalid html. I just want to declare a variable (I'll close `<table>` depending on the processing logic somewhere later).
Is there a way to workaround this or do I have to use `text` as the output type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the output method is `html`, then the processor will output `<br/>` as `<br>`. However, both the input and the stylesheet must be well-formed **XML** documents.

As for your question regarding the variable: you cannot store only a  **start-tag** in a variable. You must store an entire element (which at this point exists only as an abstraction, and has no tags).

If you find yourself "needing" to store a start-tag which you'll "*close depending on the processing logic somewhere later*", then you need to reconsider your approach. It's not a matter of finding a workaround; that's just not how XSLT works.

Answer (score 3):

XSLT is a language for transforming source trees into result trees. Forget tags and markup; they are superficial, they are only a convenient way of showing trees on your screen display. The source document is a tree, the stylesheet is a tree, and the result document is a tree. An element node whose name is "br" with no attributes and no children is shown as `<br/>` in XML notation and as `<br>` in HTML notation, but to XSLT there is no difference.

You can't "close [a tag] depending on the processing logic somewhere later". Firstly, XSLT is a functional language, there is no concept of order of processing and therefore no concept of "later". Secondly, a node on a tree is an indivisible object, you create it all at once, it doesn't have a separate beginning and end that can be created at different times.

When you read this in XSLT:

```
<p>
  <xsl:value-of select="XXXX"/>
</p>
```

you might think of that as a sequence of three operations (write a start tag, write the text content, write the end tag). But that's not the right processing model at all. There are two element nodes in this XSLT fragment, a `p` element and an `xsl:value-of` element; therefore two instructions: a `p` instruction which writes a `p` element to the result tree, and an `xsl:value-of` instruction which writes a text node to the result tree.

Answer (score 2):

Any XSLT stylesheet has to be a namespace well-formed XML document and with XML you can't have a `<br>` without a closing `</br>`. You can use `<br/>` of course in XML instead of `<br></br>`.

Comment: Ah ok. It looks like I've expected too much from the output method="html" option. So do I have to use output method="text" to do the things I mentioned in the question?

Comment: No, absolutely not. Focus on the tree, not on its serialization.